# Creating tabs in AngularJs

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to create simple tabs using only divs with ng-show and ng-hide. I don't want to use jQuery or BootStrap. I have created the tabs but I cannot handle the divs correctly.

## [*<kbd>JS Fiddle</kbd>*](http://jsfiddle.net/uDw5g/)

```
<div  ng-app ng-controller="sample">

    <div class="cb" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">tab 1</div>
    <div class="cb" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">tab 2</div>

    <div ng-hide="showDetails">
        <p>first</p>
     </div>

    <div ng-show="showDetails">
        <p>second</p>
    </div>
```

Even if I click the first tab displays the content of the second tab. 
How can I display only the first content when I click the first tab and the second content when I click the second one?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @F4r-20, are there any description about markdown like you used for JSFiddle?

Comment: @SET use the `<kbd>` tag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/x8xfM/2/

```
<div  ng-app ng-controller="sample" ng-init="tab=1">

        <div class="cb" ng-click="tab = 1">tab 1</div>
        <div class="cb" ng-click="tab = 2">tab 2</div>

        <div ng-show="tab == 1">
            <p>first</p>
         </div>

        <div ng-show="tab == 2">
            <p>second</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

In your case `showDetails = !showDetails` will switch active tab each time you click on ANY tab.

Comment: Great answer! Works nicely.